# I don't compile C# tutorial with Matlab engine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, matlab-engine

I write a tutorial C# API with Matlab using matlab.engine.
(I want to exchange data between C# and Matlab. However, I cannot use the library when compiling. How to hide error?
My code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MathWorks.MATLAB.Engine;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.Exceptions;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.Types;
using System;

namespace MathWorks.MATLAB.Engine.ConsoleExamples
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Starting MATLAB... ");
            using (dynamic matlab = MATLABEngine.StartMATLAB())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("done.");
                double[] A = matlab.linspace(-5.0, 5.0);
                int[] sz = new int[] { 25, 4 };
                double[,] B = matlab.reshape(A, sz);
            }
            // Call when you no longer need MATLAB Engine in your application.
            MATLABEngine.TerminateEngineClient();
        }
    }
}
namespace UDP_virtual
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't compile. I assume I don't add lib for C# file.

[image: my code]

Comment: Install the matlab engine : https://pypi.org/project/matlabengine/